# In general, which files and directories can be deleted from MacOS without bricking it?

Tags: macos, permission, administrator, system-requirements

I would like to make my MacOS as minimal as possible without it being unable to boot. The main reason is to reduce complexity and focus on understanding a smaller number of things before adding in more functionalities. In case someone were to say, "That isn't a good way to learn," I would say, that's your opinion, but I would like to know out of curiosity's sake which files I can delete, and which I should not.

I am pretty sure there are three permissions groups on Mac - staff, wheel, and admin, which is what you see when you do ls -l - drwxrwxrwx has three repetitions of "rwx", one for each group.

I think "sudo" causes you to enter into the second-highest permissions level, but as I tried to delete some system files with sudo, I still got the message "operation not permitted" sometimes. Is there any command to delete those even more restricted files, or is it not a function in MacOS?

What is a general explanation for which files/directories can be deleted, and which can't?

I think there are some .plist files you can delete, but what I found so far is that when you reboot, the OS realizes something is wrong and goes into recovery mode, where I am pretty sure it regenerates a lot of the files it needs (I think I had this happen for a Bluetooth settings .plist file, for example).

But I am sure there are some files that comes with MacOS by default that are not needed, for example, I think I was able to get rid of the Movies and Music directories, and some system files I can't remember, I think it might have had to do with Xcode though.

So what can I delete without impeding or harming the system? I tried sudo rm -r * in the top level directory, because I was wondering if since sudo didn't have the absolute top-level permissions, it would not delete any truly system-critical files. So far that has appeared to be the case, as my Mac is functioning fine, but I have not rebooted yet to see what happens then. When I do sudo rm -r * in / or any directory, I get a message asking if I want to override that some file cannot be deleted. I do not see any message about what the expected responses are - "yes", "y"? Does pressing enter mean yes or no? If I hold the enter key down, there can be a huge number of such messages. Is there any way to force the override for the entire command so you do not have to manually answer "yes" to seemingly hundreds of such questions?

I think some system administrators will say, "You don't want to do that, that's a bad idea," but the point is I want to know what I can do that avoids the potentially destructive outcome such people may be forewarning one about.

Thank you.

Comment: STart with a Unix tutorial or book. Your second paragragh is totally wrong. sudo is totally wrong. I haven't read the rest. You need to start from scratch and assume everything you know is totally incorrect. Luckily with new MacOS the system siles are now all in a read only volume and can't be deleted. rm is the last command you should learn.

Comment: This has been asked already.  See:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/91334/119271

Comment: You are starting off on the wrong foot and making too many assumptions.  Start off with the eBook (it's free):  [iOS/Mac OS X Internals](https://github.com/writeups/iOS/blob/master/iOS:macOS%20Books/Mac%20Os%20X%20Internals%20-%20A%20Systems%20Approach.pdf). From there you'll get an insight of how the system works, what each service does, how the file system is structured, etc. (Yes, it's a bit dated, but it's an excellent primer on macOS)

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to know out of curiosity's sake which files I can delete,
> and which I should not.

Firstly, removing anything that the system expects to find is likely to cause errors.

Secondly, macOS 'system' is now on a read-only volume that cannot normally be deleted. It is also cryptographically sealed, and attempts to modify it may result in a failure to boot.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/secd698747c9/web

The benefits of 'minimality' are ... well, minimal.

Finally, blindly deleting whatever you can and seeing what happens, is a terrible way to learn. That's not an opinion, but a didactic truth.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have misunderstood a number of things about the system. Therefore I would highly recommend that you start by reading a macOS book or general introduction texts to operating systems in the Unix family. You'll learn much quicker that way.

If you want to understand an operating system as a beginner, you want to go with an educational operating system. They're made for the purpose of being easier to understand. Modern, consumer desktop operating systems are not created to be understood by a single person - they have other goals. Simply removing files until it breaks it not really going to leave you with something so small that it is understandable by a beginner.

Just to get the misunderstandings out of the way:

1. It is not so that there are three permission groups on macOS named "staff", "wheel" and "admin". Those are user groups - a standard system comes with a lot more than those three, and you can add more if you like. See the list in `/etc/groups`.
2. It is not so that the "drwxrwxrwx" letters means permissions for each of the three aforementioned groups. Instead the letters tells you something about read, write and execute permissions for the owner, the group and others. However this is not the whole story - some types of permissions are not expressible in this simple manner.
3. It is not so that `sudo` enters the "second-highest permission level". Instead `sudo` simply allows you to run a command as another user (which could include the superuser). There are operations that in some circumstances even the superuser cannot perform.

You ask for a command to delete "restricted files" - there's no such specific command. However, you can ofcourse delete files if you want - depending on the circumstances that could be by booting up in Recovery mode or by simply mounting the file system on a different computer and deleting the file.

In terms of "restricted files", it is so that modern macOS systems have a read-only volume that contains system files. Being read-only, you cannot really delete files from it in ordinary use (you can do it in other ways ofcourse, but it is generally a bad idea).

In general there's really nothing you can delete without "impeding or harming the system" - unless you take a very subjective point of view. I.e. if you never use "Keynote", you can delete "Keynote" without feeling that harms the system. If you use it every day, you cannot really delete it without feeling that harms the system. In general, if you delete something, you'll miss out on something - it might not be something you use (like a French dictionary might be of no use for you).

Note that if you think that the system will perform "better" or "faster" after deleting these "unnecessary" data files - that's generally not the case.